# object de/serialization using dart

Tags: serialization, dart, webrtc

I have to serialize some WebRTC-related dart objects to send them over a signaling channel. As example I have to encode `RtcSessionDescription` and `RtcIceCandidate` instances. Both classes offer a constructor to build them in context of a given map, but no one offers a method to create such a Map out of the original object.

How can I generate strings? Do I have to make a detour over Map-objects?

As Example:

RtcSessionDescription -> Map -> String -(send_over_signalingChannel)-> String -> Map -> RtcSessionDescription

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I automatically serialize a Dart object to send over a Web Socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423318/can-i-automatically-serialize-a-dart-object-to-send-over-a-web-socket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution (using `dart:convert` as Günther Zöchbauer suggested):

```
RtcSessionDescription original = ...;

//serialize
final String serialized_sdp = JSON.encode({
    'sdp':original.sdp,
    'type':original.type
});


//decode
final Map sdp_map = JSON.decode(serialized_sdp);    
RtcSessionDescription sdp = new RtcSessionDescription(sdp_map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert between Map and String using the `dart:convert` package.

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/

I don't know about RtcSessionDescription <-> Map though.

See also this question: [Can I automatically serialize a Dart object to send over a Web Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423318)